# running the ramaze blog example - an error message

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ramaze

```
deltrem@deltrem-desktop:~/ramaze web/app/blog$ ruby start.rb
I [2010-06-10 14:53:33 $1886]  INFO | : activating sequel
I [2010-06-10 14:53:33 $1886]  INFO | : Installing sequel
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:124:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/deltrem/.gem/ruby/1.8/cache/sequel-3.9.0.gem (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:124:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:124:in `download'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:257:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:247:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:247:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:91:in `install_gem'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:102:in `temp_argv'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:89:in `install_gem'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:80:in `setup_gem'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:63:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:62:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:62:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:38:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:29:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ramaze-2010.04.04/lib/ramaze/setup.rb:29:in `setup'
    from ./app.rb:4
    from start.rb:3:in `require'
    from start.rb:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what this is for, but the error message seems pretty clear:

> Permission denied - /home/deltrem/.gem/ruby/1.8/cache/sequel-3.9.0.gem (Errno::EACCES)

You don't have permission to read or write to that path. Are you supposed to `sudo` this?

Comment: This line also seems pertinent: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:124:in `open'